# leaflet-geosearch OpenStreetMapProvider problem

Tags: leaflet, geocoding

I have problem with leaflet-geosearch OpenStreetMapProvider  I get an error in console:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3001' is therefore not allowed access.

[image]

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a 503 error from the Nominatim server. [50x errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors) are failures on the web server side (not on your code), and a 503 is usually a temporary overload or outage. You'll have to wait it out.

Comment: you are right i think the probleme is from the server.... itried it this morning and i get no errors  ...thx  ;)